# Scaling down mesh to fit container in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a project in which people should be able to load in their own models at runtime and walk arround on them. For this i want to scale down the meshes to fit in a container which would be the level area.

[image]
[image: Example 2 of problem]

I got the importing part working using the `ObjImporter` but I can't seem to figure out how I can scale down the imported meshes to fit the box.

This is what i tried so far:

```
public void ModelPicker() {
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

    //Choose an Obj or dxf file 
    string filePath = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel ("Select model","C:\\", "obj;*.dxf;" ); 
    if(filePath != "") {
        string[] extention = filePath.Split ('.'); //Get the extention of the chosen file
        string[] filename = filePath.Split ('/'); // Get the file name + extention of the chosen file

        if (extention [extention.Length - 1] == "obj") { //If the file had an "obj" extention, use ObjImporter
            mesh = OI.ImportFile (filePath);
        } else if (extention [extention.Length - 1] == "dxf") { //If the file had an "dxf" extention, use DxfToMesh
        //TODO  mesh = DxfToMesh (filePath);
        } else {
            GameObject.Find ("FilePathText").GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text> ().text = "Format not supported.";   //if the file had an unsupported extention
        }

        if (mesh != null) {
            GameObject em = GameObject.Find ("emptyModel");
            em.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh = mesh; //Display the loaded model 
            GameObject.Find ("FilePathText").GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text> ().text = filename[filename.Length -1]; //Display filename

            //Should decrease size to fit in the box 
            int counter = 0; // to make sure the loop will end eventually
            em.renderer.bounds.SetMinMax(em.transform.parent.collider.bounds.min, em.transform.parent.collider.bounds.max);
            Debug.Log("max: " + em.renderer.bounds.max + "  |  min: " + em.renderer.bounds.min);
            Debug.Log("parent max: " + em.transform.collider.bounds.max + "  |  parent min: " + em.transform.collider.bounds.min);
            while(em.renderer.collider.bounds.Intersects(em.transform.parent.collider.bounds) && counter < 100)
            {
                Debug.Log (em.transform.localScale );
                em.transform.localScale *= 0.9f;
                counter++;
                if(counter == 100) {
                    Debug.Log("max: " + em.renderer.bounds.max + "  |  min: " + em.renderer.bounds.min);
                }
            }
            GameObject.Find("SimulateButton").GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        }
    }
}
```

`emptyModel` is the GameObject that contains the imported model. It has a parent with a boxcollider and without a mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright I have it figured out now.

I can take the x,y,z value from the `extends` of the mesh to get the farthest points. Then in a `while` loop  I check if these points are all in the `bounds` of the parent. If they aren't within the `bounds` I multiply the scale by 0.9. Then it'll repeat untill it fits in the box

```
public void ModelPicker() {
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();

    //Choose an Obj or dxf file 
    string filePath = UnityEditor.EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel ("Select model","C:\\", "obj;*.dxf;" ); 
    if(filePath != "") {
        string[] extention = filePath.Split ('.'); //Get the extention of the chosen file
        string[] filename = filePath.Split ('/'); // Get the file name + extention of the chosen file

        if (extention [extention.Length - 1] == "obj") { //If the file had an "obj" extention, use ObjImporter
            mesh = OI.ImportFile (filePath);
        } else if (extention [extention.Length - 1] == "dxf") { //If the file had an "dxf" extention, use DxfToMesh
        //  mesh = DxfToMesh (filePath);
        } else {
            GameObject.Find ("FilePathText").GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text> ().text = "Format not supported.";   //if the file had an unsupported extention
        }

        if (mesh != null) {
            GameObject em = GameObject.Find ("emptyModel");
            em.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1);
            em.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh = mesh; //Display the loaded model 
            GameObject.Find ("FilePathText").GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text> ().text = filename[filename.Length -1]; //Display filename
            Vector3 parentSize = em.transform.parent.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().bounds.size;

            while(em.transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().renderer.bounds.extents.x > parentSize.x || 
                  em.transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().renderer.bounds.extents.y > parentSize.y || 
                  em.transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().renderer.bounds.extents.z > parentSize.z  
                 ) {
                em.transform.localScale *= 0.9f;
            }
            GameObject.Find("SimulateButton").GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
        }
    }
}
```